# (C++) Why have I seen some programmers do this with classes when I was taught to separate declarations and implementations?

Tags: c++, class, layout, conventions, declare

I was shown this code, and it compiles. No surprises there, but why was it organized the way it was? Why is there no `class.cpp`?
(Edit: I don't mean in terms of whitespace, I mean in terms of placement.)

```cpp
/// main.cpp ///
#include <iostream>
#include "class.h"

int main() {
    Pet a(4);
    double x;
    std::cout << "How much does this weigh? "; std::cin >> x;
    Pet b(x);
    Pet c(b);
    std::cout << "You have " << a.getTotal() << " pets." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "a weighs " << a.getWeight() << " pounds." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b weighs " << b.getWeight() << " pounds." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "c weighs " << c.getWeight() << " pounds." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```cpp
/// class.h ///
#ifndef CLASS_H_
#define CLASS_H_

class Pet {
private:
    double weight;
    static int total;
public:
    Pet()                           { weight = 0; upTotal(); }
    Pet(double w)                   { weight = w; upTotal(); }
    Pet(const Pet& that)            { this->weight = that.weight; upTotal(); }
    double getWeight()              { return weight; }
    void setWeight (double w)       { weight = w; }
    int getTotal()                  { return total; }
    void upTotal()                  { ++total; }
    void downTotal()                { --total; }
};

int Pet::total = 0;

#endif // CLASS_H_
```

I was told that it is good practice to separate class declarations into header files and leave the insides for a source file. But here these functions are being defined in the header file instead of just being declared.

I didn't think much else of it after that, until I looked into a header file belonging to an IDE for GUIs, and I see lots of class methods being organized the same exact way. Why is this?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having declarations use inline definitions for small methods for performance reasons.  The `Pet::total` variable, on the other hand, would be a problem if `class.h` were ever included in multiple `.cpp` files. Each `.cpp` would get its own copy of the variable, breaking the [One Definition Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition).

Comment: If you're lazy and/or it's just a trivial definition this is fine.

Comment: @RemyLebeau How would I avoid that when including it into multiple ```.cpp``` files?

Comment: Nasty code. No `const` correctness. `getTotal` should be `static`. Compiler generated assignment operator is inadequate. And so on.

Comment: @PatrickO'Brien: Write `int Pet::total = 0;` in a single cpp file.

Comment: As of C++17, you can have an inline static variable: just prepend `inline` to form `inline int Pet::total = 0;`.  More generally, someone's just done this for ease of understanding/maintaining very simple classes.  It doesn't scale well, partly because when you edit the implementation client code has to be recompiled.  If it was in a separate .cpp, client code could just relink - that's faster.  Also because it gets visually cluttered with larger function bodies.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm not sure there is anything to gain in performance from having member function definitions in the class definition. Most compilers are capable of link time optimizations now. Inlining can happen across translation units.

Comment: The usual reason (valid reason) cited is performance, which is because the compiler can inline the functions as if they were typed directly into the callsite.  With WPO or LTO, that's no longer a concern, but once we have C++20 **modules** it'll probably all be moot anyway.  And there's lots of existing C++ code in the wild, which will be around for a very long time.

Comment: in your example it makes literelly no difference whether there is a header and source or all is in the header. What you compile is the source. Only when you include the same header in several translation units you will notice a differnce

Comment: You should also consider maintenance or build times when placing code into a header file.  If you change the code in a header file, then all source files that include the header file will rebuild (because the header file changed).  By placing the code into a source file, if you change the code, only one file needs to be rebuilt.